# How to match two Textarea words through script

Tags: javascript

I want to get the script by which i can match the words off both text boxes with colring effects and on wrong word entering the error will come !

Please check this link to understand what i am saying ( English / Hindi )

https://www3.digialm.com//OnlineAssessment/index.html?164@@M325

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? Please give an attempt before posting the question.

Comment: We cannot view the site, as it is password protected... unless it is that login page you want us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the oninput event to check the contents of both boxes, then add a class to a "warning" one to the boxes if they don't match, and change that class to a "you're okay" one if they do match.

```
textbox1.oninput = check;
textbox2.oninput = check;

function check() {
  if (textbox2.value !== textbox1.value) {
    textbox1.className = "warning";
    textbox2.className = "warning";
  }
  else {
    textbox1.className = "";
    textbox2.className = "";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want script for `Typing test` kind of application or game. If this is your requirement then you can check this [link](http://www.javascriptsource.com/games/typing-test.html).